# How to filter lines in two files where the value in a specific column has the same sign (- or +)?

Tags: text-processing

I have two files which look as follows:

- `file1`:

  ```
  6:66893424_T_C -0.5985 
  rs151222586 -0.0351 
  rs12364336 -0.0030 
  rs57502521 0.0099
  ```
- `file2`:

  ```
  6:66893424_T_C 0.5985
  rs151222586 -0.0351
  rs12364336 0.003
  rs57502521 -0.0099
  ```

I would like to:

- find those lines where column 2 has the same sign (minus or plus)
- create a list of column1 entries where the signs match
- create a list of column1 entries where the does not match

I would like:

- a matched output as

  ```
  rs151222586
  ```
- and an unmatched output as

  ```
  6:66893424_T_C
  rs12364336
  rs57502521
  ```

Comment: (1) There is no `+` in your example. I guess "no sign" should be equivalent to (and therefore match) `+` if `+` ever occurs. And I guess "no sign" shouldn't match `-`, unless maybe the number is zero. Should `+0` match `-0`? If you tell us it's about matching signs of *numbers* then we will see it like mathematicians do. But it's not obvious you want it this way. (2) Your example uses numbers that are equal or opposite. But we shouldn't care about the values, only about the signs, right?

Comment: (3) If one of the files contains e.g. `rs12 0.1` but there is no `rs12` in the other file, should `rs12` appear in the "unmatched" output? or should it be omitted?

Comment: Are the columns space- or tab-separated?

Answer (score 6):

paste+awk the files side-by-side so that we get to compare the second field with the fourth:

```
paste file1 file2 |
awk '
  $2&&$4 {
    print $1 > ($2*$4>0?"match":"unmatch")
  }
'
```

Results are in the files match and unmatched.

Answer (score 4):

Dealing with multiple input files is a chore, it's easier if the data is folded to a single file. E.g. `paste` or `join` can do that:

```
$ paste file1 file2
6:66893424_T_C -0.5985  6:66893424_T_C 0.5985
rs151222586 -0.0351     rs151222586 -0.0351
rs12364336 -0.0030      rs12364336 0.003
rs57502521 0.0099       rs57502521 -0.0099

$ join -j1 file1 file2
6:66893424_T_C -0.5985  0.5985
rs151222586 -0.0351  -0.0351
rs12364336 -0.0030  0.003
rs57502521 0.0099  -0.0099
```

The former counts on the order being correct. In both cases, you should probably check for cases where the files don't conform with each other.

Using the output from `paste`, the entries where the signs differ:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '($2 >= 0) != ($4 >= 0) {print $1}'
6:66893424_T_C
rs12364336
rs57502521
```

`>=` evaluates to `1` or `0`, so using `!=` to compare the comparison results like that works. I arbitrarily chose to align zeroes as positive.
Similarly use `==` for equal signs.

We could also define the sign function explicitly:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk 'function sign(x) { return x >= 0 ? +1 : -1; }
                           sign($2) != sign($4) {print $1}'
6:66893424_T_C
rs12364336
rs57502521
```

Comment: +1 for a fast xor based solution. Wish awk had the facility to get sign of a num.

Answer (score 1):

Since `awk` has no facility to perform line-by-line operations on two files, a certain amount of buffering will be required. It can work if your files are small enough.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{v[$1]=$2; next}
     {if ($2*v[$1]>=0) {print $1 > "matched"} else {print $1 > "unmatched"}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

- When reading `file1.txt`, this will only record the "label"-"value"-pairs in an array `v`, and skip execution to the next input line. The distinction whether we are processing `file1.txt` or `file2.txt` is made by checking if the per-file line counter `FNR` is equal to the global line counter `NR`. If they are equal, we are processing the first file.
- When reading `file2.txt`, it will check whether the product of the "value" part of the current line and the corresponding value from `file1.txt` are zero or positive. If so, their signs are equal, and the "label" part is output to a file `matched`. If it is negative, the signs are unequal, and the "label" part is output to a file `unmatched`.

Results:

```
~ > cat matched 
rs151222586

~ > cat unmatched
6:66893424_T_C
rs12364336
rs57502521
```

**Note**

- I assumed that `+0` and `-0` are considered as having equal sign.
- I also assumed that there can be no lines where the column 2 value in either file is 0 while it is non-zero in the other.